# Blind, compulsive adherence to the rules, regardless of circumstance

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology, synonyms, noun-phrases

I'm looking for a word, term, or phrase that refers to a type of behaviour; somewhat similar to what's commonly known as *"Malicious Compliance"*; but without the necessary implication of malice aforethought.

That is to say; the behaviour in question is characterised by a strict, blind adherence to the rules. Regardless of (or ignorant to) the potentially negative impact it may have or the damage it could cause without considering any unique, individual, or extenuating circumstances. Possibly even to the detriment of the system that the rules are intended to protect.

Comment: To everyone else; I sincerely apologize and thank you for your contribution(s).

Answer (score 0):

In British English a person acting in such a way can be referred to as a [jobsworth](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/jobsworth). The term is derived from the supposed tendency of people with that mentality to say "I can't let you do that, it'd be more that my *job's worth*!" implying that, if his supervisor caught him bending the rules, he would be dismissed.

This would be a reasonable attitude to take to serious breaches of security or safety but the term 'jobsworth' is used disparagingly to describe the "Ignorantly Compliant", the "Maliciously Compliant" and those who pretend that rules exist which prevent their doing something which they do not wish to do.

The term is rather less common than it used to be but is still understood and the phrase "Ooh, more than my job's worth!" is often used humorously, particularly between colleagues who understand the reality of the situation.

If you want to refer to the behaviour of an individal you could say that they were "being a jobsworth" or were "acting like a jobsworth". The tendency to act in that manner can also be described as a "jobsworth attitude"

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean ***bureaucratic*** behavior.

ODO:

> **[bureaucratic](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bureaucratic)**
> *ADJECTIVE*
>
> **1.1** Over-concerned with procedure *at the expense of efficiency or common sense*:
>
> ‘the scheme is overly bureaucratic and complex’
>
> ‘During time-critical events, this bureaucratic delay can result in
> missed opportunities by satellites with limited observation windows.
> ’‘Too many of their proposed improvements and developments of services
> were frustrated by what they perceived as bureaucratic hurdles.’